# Referencing instance attribute in template passed from view.py - django 2.0

Tags: django, django-templates

Hopefully a simple one...

```
views.py
def View(request):
    queryset = Example.objects.all()
    for obj in queryset :
        obj.x = 'String attribute added to model instance.'
    context = {'queryset ': queryset }
    return render(request, 'app/template.html', context=context)

template.html
{% for obj in queryset.all %}
    {{ obj.x }}
{% endfor %}
```

According to Stefano Contini's [article](https://www.abidibo.net/blog/2012/10/02/django-add-properties-model-instances/) this should work but in my example {{obj.x}} is not pulling through the string. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: No - as in the queryset contains multiple objects @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: Is this your *full* code?

Comment: no its been simplified for the question - @daniel roseman

Comment: Which parts? We really need to see what is actually happening. If you do anything that causes `queryset` to be re-evaluated in some way, Django will go back to the database and your changes will be lost.

Comment: Ok in that case would it be better to edit the question to contain all the code? @DanielRoseman

Comment: @DanielRoseman your question has solved the problem! I had {% for obj in queryset.all %} but this should be {% for obj in queryset %} - thanks

Answer (score 0):

{% for obj in queryset.all %} is incorrect

{% for obj in queryset %} is correct

Thanks @Daniel Roseman for asking the question that answered the question